# What is the best way to create remote tunnel?

Tags: ssh, port, tunnel

I have 3 Linux servers:
- 10.0.0.0/24 - (10.0.0.10) Linux server inside my LAN.
- 20.0.0.0/24 - (20.0.0.10) Linux server with HTTP Apache server
- 50.50.50.50/32 - Server on Amazon AWS which see both 10.x and 20.x LANs.

10.x cannot see 20.x and 20.x cannot see 10.x
What is the best way (and how can I do it) to se 50.50.50.50 server on AWS to create tunnel from 10.x to 20.x

For example, if 20.x runs HTTPd, I want to be able to go to 50.50.50.50:80 from 10.x servers and see 20.x:80 content .

Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to belong to http://serverfault.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Login to `50.50.50.50` and run

```
ssh -L 50.50.50.50:80:20.x:80 username@20.x
```

and enter your password for user@20.x.

Now, if you connect to `50.50.50.50:80` from `10.x` you should see the HTTPd on 20.x.

You can add a `-N` to not execute a remote command. 
Add a `-f -N` to background the ssh process.

cheers,